# How do I know which Thread called my Log method?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging

I have a Log class that has several static methods which help log information about my program.

My problem is that I have 2 threads running and both of them send requests to my Log class to log information.

I would like to have my Log class show which threads are logging which lines.

What should I do to achieve this functionality?

My code is basically like this:

```
 public class Log {
     public static void log ( String tag , Object message ) 
     {
         String lineToPrint = "";
         //Builds the string taking in time data and other information
         //...
         //This is where I want to see which thread called this log function
         //...

         System.out.println( lineToPrint );
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you use one of the existing log frameworks such as log4j (possibly wrapped using apache commons logging)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your logger:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
String name = t.getName();
```

and dump it to log file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Temp{
   static Thread t = null;
}
```

temp.t = Thread.currentThread();

```
 public static void log ( String tag , Object message ) 
 {
         temp.t.getName();//get it
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, with respect to `pthread`s, the function for knowing about the calling thread is: `pthread_t pthread_self (void);`

Reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_self.html

Comment: yeah, I know pthreads haven't been mentioned in the OP, but it may help someone else.